# Create dynamic reactive form using json file - Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I'm tried to create dynamic reactive form using json file but didn't worked with me.

This the json file :

```
 "inputs":[
    {
      "formcontrol":"email",
      "validation":["required,email"]
    },
    {
      "formcontrol":"password",
      "validation":["required"]
    },
    {
      "formcontrol":"firstname",
      "validation":["required"]
    },
    {
      "formcontrol":"lastname",
      "validation":["required"]
    }
  ]
```

This what I tried :

```
for(let input of inputs ) // json data
{
   this.t.push(this.formBuilder.group({
      input.formcontrol: ['', input.validation],
   }));
}
```

I know what I did isn't correct but I have no clue how to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add only `formControl` dynamically as per the formGroup like below -

```
inputs =[
    {
      "formcontrol":"email",
      "validation":["required,email"]
    },
    ....
  ];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.SignupForm = this.fb.group({});
    let control = new FormControl('');

    for(let input of this.inputs) {
      this.SignupForm.addControl(input.formcontrol, control);
    } 

    console.log(this.SignupForm.value);
  }
```

[Working Example Snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-reactive-formsss?file=app/app.component.ts)

If needed you may refer official Documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addcontrol)

Comment: Can you please answer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74735567/how-to-create-a-dynamic-reactive-form

Answer (score 0):

Here's example of creating dynamic form controls

```
inputs: any = <json data>;
formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

ngOnInit(): void {
    // process json data
    this.inputs.forEach(value => {
        this.formGroup.addControl(
            value.formcontrol, // control name
            new FormControl("", this.getValidators(value.validation))
        );
    });
}

// method that returns angular validators from strings
private getValidators(validatorsList: Array<string>): Array<ValidatorFn> {
    const validators: Array<ValidatorFn> = [];

    // map string validators to angular validators
    validatorsList.forEach((validator: string) => {
        switch (validator) {
           case "required":
               validators.push(Validators.required);
               break;
           case "email":
               validators.push(Validators.email);
               break;
           default:
           break;
        }
    });

    return validators;
}
```

I also created [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wt62md?file=src/app/app.component.ts), check console to see result.

Comment: Link only answers are never encouraged!

Comment: Sorry, fixed for now :)